# How to extract password protected zip files using Apache Spark(Scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have written the below code to read zip file without password as below:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("CSVProcessSPark");                                         //create a new spark config
            val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)  


            sc.binaryFiles("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/HWZ.zip", 1)                           //make an RDD from *.zip files in HDFS
            .flatMap((file: (String, PortableDataStream)) => {                  //flatmap to unzip each file
                val zipStream = new ZipInputStream(file._2.open)   

                //open a java.util.zip.ZipInputStream
                val entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()                             //get the first entry in the stream
                val iter = Source.fromInputStream(zipStream).getLines           //place entry lines into an iterator
                iter.next                                                       //pop off the iterator's first line
                iter                                                            //return the iterator
            })
            .saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/result.csv")
```

I tried setting password in spark context local property, but still i was not able to read a password protected zip file.

Kindly provide me a solution to read password protected zip file using Apache Spark.

Thanks in advance.